# InternalViewResolver not working in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created a test Spring MVC project . Here the controller is getting executed but later to that the internalview resolver is not able to convert the logical name as when I hit the URL I get "HTTP Status 404 -The requested resource () is not available." on the browser but the SOP inside the controller is getting executed.

Web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>    

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>spring/mvc/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config> -->
</web-app>
```

Controller Code :

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/Welcome")
public String  displaywelcomePage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("Into the controller");
    return "Welcome";
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">


<annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc.prac.springmvcprac" />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

  <beans:bean          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />  
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>                       

</beans:beans>
```

servlet-context.xml  lies in webapp/spring/mvc

Welcome.jsp lies in webapp/WEB-INF/view

Comment: Where are you deploying to? Is there `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` present in your apps classpath?

Comment: I am deploying on tomcat server and javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config is not present. My JSP is very simple it does not contain any jstl tajs

Comment: Please see my answer. If `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` is not present the view class is not automagically configured.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the web.xml for changed the appservlet URL pattern from /* to /

appServlet
/

Although this issue is solved but actually I didnt understood the root cause as anyhow previously also the controller was getting called

Answer (score 0):

Your config is missing the view class. Change

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />  
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

to

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />  
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Even after adding the JstlView , I am facing the same issue. PSB the servlet-context.xml

Comment: What do you mean by PSB?

Comment: .Please see below(PSB) : I was about to add the contents of xml again  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />  
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </beans:bean>